# Flutter : The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'

Tags: image, flutter, dart, icons, flutter-assetimage

I want to use my image from assets as an icon, and then I build my lists, but there are some errors that occurred when trying to add `Image.asset` as a class to the icon as a variable with `IconData` as data type, instead of using Icons as a class.

Any idea to fix this problem?

Thank you.

```
class Menu {
  const Menu({this.icon, this.title});

  final IconData icon;
  final String title;
}

const List<Menu> menus = const <Menu>[
  const Menu(title: 'menu_icon_1', icon: Image.asset('assets/menu/1-1.png')),
],
```

```
error: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [sinergi] lib\home.dart:12)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please use ImageIcon

```
class Menu {
  const Menu({this.icon, this.title});

  final ImageIcon icon;
  final String title;
}

const List<Menu> menus = const <Menu>[
  const Menu(title: 'menu_icon_1', icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/menu/1-1.png'))),
];
```

Comment: The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Icon?'.

Comment: SideMenuItem(
        priority: 0,
        title: 'Dashboard',
        onTap: (index, _) {
          sideMenu.changePage(index);
        },
        icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/menu/1-1.png')),
        badgeContent: const Text(
          '3',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),

Comment: what should i do?

Answer (score -1):

if you want default icon

```
class Menu {
    const Menu({this.icon, this.title});

    final IconData icon;
    final String title;
}

const List<Menu> menus = const <Menu>[
    const Menu(title: 'Trending', icon: Icons.trending_up),
    const Menu(title: 'Favorite', icon: Icons.favorite),
    const Menu(title: 'Search', icon: Icons.search),
    const Menu(title: 'Category', icon: Icons.category),
    const Menu(title: 'Settings', icon: Icons.settings),
];
```